# IIS 7.5 Different ssl certificate with different domain name on same ip

Tags: ssl, iis

have an IIS 7.5 (win 2008 r2) server and i want to bind the same web site to 2 different domain and to 2 different certificates.

I can't use wildcard since the domains are different FQDNs.

If i add 2 bindings for https and port 443 i can't select 2 different certificates (when i change one binding it changes the other).

There is a way to solve this without using different port or splitting to 2 different websites?

Answer (score 3):

IIS 7.5 does not support [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI), meaning, each separate TLS site needs its own IP address.

You need to get a second public IP and a second site to host two different domains via TLS. Or upgrade to Server 201x

Answer (score 2):

If upgrading to a version of IIS that supports [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI) is not feasible, you might be able to use a single certificate, with both FQDNs listed in the [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) field.